# Spring Boot - How to save an audited entity as "System" when using user based auditing?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-session

I'm working with an audited entity in my Spring Boot app (`@CreatedBy`, `@LastModifiedBy` etc.) and setting the current auditor with a session scoped bean based on the current logged in user. The auditing with a logged in user works just fine. But I'm also periodically pulling data with `@Scheduled` and I need to save the pulled data as the audited entity into my DB. The problem is that trying to save an audited entity without a logged in user still calls `getCurrentAuditor()` in `AuditorAwareImpl` which gets the current user from a session scoped bean, which is set when the user logs in, but beacause there is no user or session it causes this error:

`Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread;`

So basically I need my audited entity to be able to be saved by logged in users but also by the "System" (without a logged in user). Is there a reasonable solution to this problem or is my approach just wrong?

Comment: Change your `getCurrentAuditor()` implementation to return a dummy "System" user in the case there is no user or session.

Comment: @ChinHuang I've already tried, but I didn't find a way to check if the session scoped bean exists or not. Right now I'm just working around it with a try/catch. So that if it throws an exception when getting the session scoped bean I return the dummy user. Which is not ideal to say the least.